# Configuring relationships between 2 TPH types using Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api, tph

I have 2 abstract classes: Configuration and Room. Both of those have 2 concrete implementations for Coworking and Meeting (CoworkingRoomConfiguration, MeetingRoomConfiguration, MeetingRoom and CoworkingRoom).

Both are configured to have a discriminator column using Fluent API:

Room:

```
builder.ToTable(nameof(Room));
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Type")
    .HasValue<MeetingRoom>("Meeting")
    .HasValue<CoworkingRoom>("Coworking");
```

Configuration:

```
builder.ToTable(nameof(Configuration));
builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
builder.HasDiscriminator<string>("Room_type")
    .HasValue<MeetingRoomConfiguration>("Meeting")
    .HasValue<CoworkingRoomConfiguration>("Cowork");
```

In my domain, a CoworkingRoom has one CoworkingRoomConfiguration. A MeetingRoom has many MeetingRoomConfigurations, though. Is it possible to explicitly declare these relationships using Fluent API, while keeping the types configured as TPH?

Right now I'm relying on EF Core inferring the relationships based on property types, but this isn't something I'd like to rely on.

Classes are below, the Entity type is based on [this article](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/entity-base-class/)

Room classes:

```
public abstract class Room : Entity
{
    // Omitted for brevity
}

public class MeetingRoom : Room
{
    public ICollection<MeetingRoomConfiguration> Configurations { get; }
    // Rest omitted for brevity
}

public class CoworkingRoom : Room
{
    public CoworkingRoomConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    // Rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Configuration classes:

```
public abstract class Configuration : Entity
{
    // Omitted for brevity
}

public class CoworkingRoomConfiguration : Configuration
{
    // Omitted for brevity
}

public class MeetingRoomConfiguration : Configuration
{
    // I'd like to get rid of the circular reference here too if possible
    public IEnumerable<MeetingRoom> MeetingRooms { get; set; }
    // Rest omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "based on property names"? Relationships are inferred from navigation property *types*, not names. And are configured fluently starting with  `Has{One|Many}` + `With{One|Many}` + relationship configuration. Nothing special for TPH if relationships are defined between concrete types I guess. Can we see the model classes?

Comment: @IvanStoev I've edited the question to include the classes. You are also correct, it's types, not names. I got confused for a second. Where my biggest point of confusion lies is explicitly defining the relationships between the concrete types, not the base types.

Comment: Ok, now forget about TPH, TPT etc. and just configure them like relationships between normal entities. From the shown partial navigations it's unclear, so you first need to define the desired relationships cardinality - one-to-one (and who is the principal and who - the dependent), one-to-many (and who is the one and who - the many) or many-to-many. Then just use the corresponding [fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key).

Comment: I see, so if I remove the `MeetingRooms` property from `MeetingRoomConfiguration`, and add `modelBuilder.Entity<MeetingRoom>().HasMany(r => r.Configurations).WithOne();` and `modelBuilder.Entity<CoworkingRoom>().HasOne(r => r.Configuration).WithOne().HasForeignKey<CoworkingRoom>();` to `OnModelCreating` EF Core will handle everything else, am I on the right track here?

Comment: Yes, something like this. Just `IEnumerable<MeetingRoom> MeetingRooms` is unclear and not mapped with this fluent configuration, so either remove it or rethink `MeetingRoom` <-> `MeetingRoomConfiguration` relationship (many-to-many?). Because if you leave it unmapped, EF Core will consider it to be a separate (3rd) relationship. Cheers.